# Получение Thread родительского потока

Tags: java, многопоточность

Мне необходимо  в процедуре main запустить дополнительный поток, который будет считывать информацию и по некоторому ее значению, а главный родительский поток приостановить.

Каким образом можно получить главный поток?

Comment: А что значит приостановить?

Comment: @cy6erGn0m: в наихудшем случае [suspend](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#suspend%28%29).

Comment: Приостановить главный поток?

Answer (score 1):

1. Передайте нужные параметры в thread-процедуру, вот вам [ссылка](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) на документацию с примерами.
2. Для синхронизации используйте не ручное управление потоками (боже упаси), а, например, [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы главный поток приостановился и подождал завершения дополнительного потока, надо после запуска добавить `join()`:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //код дополнительного потока
    }
};
thread.start();
thread.join();
```

Управлять основным потоком из дополнительного потока - в большинстве случаев не очень хорошее решение. Попробуйте организовать логику таким образом, чтобы такой необходимости не возникло.